# Beamer presentation transitions: would like a pause between a block title and block description

Tags: beamer, block, pause

I'm using blocks as a way to present important terms and their definitions.  I use the term as the block title and the definition as the block description.  I'd like to present the term, pause to ask the class about the term, and then present the definition.  I've tried `\pause`, `\onslide<#>`, and `\only<#>` but they all just show the entire block at once.  Can anyone suggest a method to perform this task?

```
\begin{block}
  {\only<1>{TERM}}
  {\only<2>{DEFINITION}}
\end{block}
```

Thanks,

james

Comment: please extend your code sniped to small, complete document, which we can copy and test in our computers. help us to help you! welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks for the brackets @AboAmmar, they nearly provided the implementation I desired.  The following does exactly as I want: 
 `\begin{block}

    {\onslide<+->{TERM}}

    {\onslide<+->{DEFINITION}}

  \end{block}`

Answer (score 2):

This depends if you want to show and empty block body on the first slide. A few possibilities:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Term}
    \only<2>{DEFINITION}
\end{block}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Term}
    \visible<2>{DEFINITION}
\end{block}
\end{frame}     

\end{document}
```